# Basic Chat using elm-native-ui

Tags: elm

I'm creating a basic native chat app with elm-native-ui.

I can open or close the chat by clicking on a button that change the chatOpen boolean

```
activeChannelView =
    case chatOpen of
        True ->
            Maybe.map (\a -> chatView users a messages) activeChannel ? viewEmpty

        False ->
            Maybe.map (cardView users) activeChannel ? viewEmpty
```

on the False side, it’s working well but on the True side it says that viewEmpty needs to be a (String -> Node Msg) instead of being (Node Msg) but the left side (chatView user a messages) returns Node Msg

Check the error below

```
The right side of (?) is causing a type mismatch.

Maybe.map (\a -> chatView users a messages)  activeChannel ? viewEmpty

^^^^^^^^^
(?) is expecting the right side to be a:

String -> Node Msg

But the right side is:

    Node Msg
```

I suppose it means that:
if activeChannel is (Just a), True returns (String -> Node Msg)

How is it possible to have this error since chatView is defined like that:

```
chatView : List User -> Request -> List String -> String -> Node Msg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chatView takes four parameters and you are passing only three.